How to keep graphic TTY session running at background
Using debian 12, kde 6
My intention is to use my pc as streaming platform for two, meaning that 2 game instances will run at once. First gaming session will run directly on the pc itself, and the second one, running at background, will be redirected to laptop to control the second game instance from there.
Current configuration I got is 2 steam clients running at different kde sessions (TTYs) under different users. Second session is streaming to laptop via Steam Link.
The problem is, after I launch the second session and switch back to the main session, the stream to steam-link-client-laptop stops immediately, meaning the session or steam process are freezing.
Is there a way to keep 2 graphical TTY session running simultaneously?

"graphical TTY" is a self-contradicting term. A tty is a text device!

but what you mean is clear enough: yes, it's possible, but not the way you're approaching this. You need to do this via a dedicated graphical environment. Something like sunshine running on a GPU-enabled headless session, not as a regular wayland/X11 user session

Perhaps what is meant by "TTY" here is actually an X server?
